# Deleting DLL from bin directory causes compile errors in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, build

i have a project say `MyProject`. It is an **asp.net MVC project**. In **bin** directory, i have deleted a DLL named **MyProject.dll**. Now when i try to build the project, i am getting following error.

> The name MyProject does not exist in
>   the current context.

In my view files and controller, there are a lot of code like

```
MyProject.Models;
```

or

```
MyProject.Utility.IsValidEmail(email);
```

how to build this solution?

Answer (score 1):

obviously, the MyProject.dll is the compiled code of the MyProject instance. WHy did you delete it?

Comment: @Martin When i build the project, the DLL is not updated in bin folder. it was still old and i was unable to see my code updates. so i removed the DLL. After removing, i got the problem that I described in question.

Comment: if its a separate project, reference that project file to the main project.

Comment: it is an asp.net mvc project.